# adding buttons to android action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can i make the buttons with text,with images in action bar like below.

Is it possible to use Inbuilt android button or image button to do like below in action bar.

I am using appcompat to use action bar.

[image]

Comment: Please consider not using IOS style buttons in an Android app. Users tend not to like it.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can inflate a custom actionbar if you need.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActionBar()
            .getThemedContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_custom, null);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
                    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView,
            new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Where actionbar_custom.xml would be your layout resource, usually a LinearLayout with whatever components you want.

Comment: is it possible to apply custom actionbar in the androidManifest itself?

Comment: No, you can't add items to the actionbar from the manifest. You can use a theme to configure the displayOptions, but you will have to inflate the view and put it in the actionbar programatically. If you want to apply a custom actionbar to a number of different activities, just add the necessary code to the onCreate method of a base activity and have the others extend it.

Comment: But. My Problem is when i set the cutom view through my code, Default action bar appears for few seconds then only custom view appears.

Comment: Have you tried configuring the actionbar before calling setContentView in your activity?

Comment: No . I just set the theme like this. android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"

Comment: The activity is not shown until the call to setContentView, so you should try making any update to the UI, like replacing the actionbar for a custom view, before the call to setContentView. I have updated the example above.

Comment: how to add click events to button in action bar

Comment: If you have inflated your custom actionbar, you have to manually set up the listeners you want. In the example above, something like customActionBarView.findViewById(...).setOnClickListener(...) would work.

Answer (score 3):

You mean action items?http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

You need to create a menu layout, as the guide mentioned above describes.

The default icon set for Android could be found here: http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Comment: Apart from the default icon set , how can  I make a custom action item like above.