# How do I achieve accordion list in mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I want to achieve something like the attached mockup which has 3 menu items

[image]

Comment: Please mention in which platform are you targeting?

Comment: native iOS and native Android

Comment: look at my answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**iOS**

The top bar is called as `navigation bar`. It has a property to set multiple bar button icons on left or right. You can use the below code to set your bar buttons.

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[rightNumber, rightPlus]
```

You can create your bar buttons programmatically and just return the array.

For android [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346434/adding-buttons-to-android-action-bar) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html#ActionItems) can be helpful.